# Compare value in DF struct array spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following problem to solve with spark/scala

I have this DF

```
+--------------+--------------------+
|co_tipo_arquiv|          errorCodes|
+--------------+--------------------+
|            05|[10531, 20524, 10...|
```

this schema:

```
root
 |-- co_tipo_arquiv: string (nullable = true)
 |-- errorCodes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I need to check if any of the codes in my error list(list_erors) are in the df in the errorCodes column

```
val list_erors = List("10531","10144")
```

i try this, but doesn't work

dfNire.filter(col("errorCodes").isin(list_erors)).show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check/list out if the array contains any **`list_errors`** then:

```
df.show()
//+------------------+
//|        errorCodes|
//+------------------+
//|[10531, 20254, 10]|
//|              [10]|
//+------------------+


def is_exists_any(s: Seq[String]): UserDefinedFunction = udf((c: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => c.toList.intersect(s).nonEmpty)

val list_errors = Seq("10531", "10144")

df.withColumn("is_exists",is_exists_any(list_errors)(col("errorCodes"))).filter(col("is_exists") === true).show()

//+------------------+---------+
//|        errorCodes|is_exists|
//+------------------+---------+
//|[10531, 20254, 10]|     true|
//+------------------+---------+
```

---

Another way to get rows without using udf would be using array_intersect and then only list out the rows where **`size of array`** is not `0`.

```
df.withColumn("is_exists", array_intersect(col("errorCodes"), lit(list_errors))).
filter(size(col("is_exists")) !==0).
show()
//+------------------+---------+
//|        errorCodes|is_exists|
//+------------------+---------+
//|[10531, 20254, 10]|  [10531]|
//+------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Nice Dude, it worked. Thank you. Brazil thanks you for your help. haha

Answer (score 1):

**Spark 2.4+**

You can use the `array_intersect` function with the array of errors.

```
val list_errors = Array("10531","10144")

df.withColumn("intersect", array_intersect(col("errors"), lit(list_errors))).show(false)
```

Then, the result is as follws:

```
+---+---------------------+---------+
|id |errors               |intersect|
+---+---------------------+---------+
|05 |[10531, 20524, 11111]|[10531]  |
+---+---------------------+---------+
```

where the column name is temporal for my test.

Comment: import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_intersect, array, lit}


No longer finding or array_intersect in spark functions

im using scala 2.11.11 and spark 2.3.0

Comment: @LeonardoGusmão Oh I see, this function is usable at the spark version 2.4+.